# Method not being executed in API 28 Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sms

I was using a method created to read in sms messages from a particualr number and load it into a listview with the help from this question that I posted. [SMS Messages of a particular number not showing up on other devices Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737288/sms-messages-of-a-particular-number-not-showing-up-on-other-devices-android/55777967?noredirect=1#comment98290866_55777967).

The method getAllSms(getContext()); is no longer being called on API Level 28. I don't understand why it's no longer working because I haven't changed anything because it was working completely fine before. Even if I put a breakpoint on where the method is being called, it's just being ignored, but on API level 22 it's working completely fine.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_commands_view, container, false);

      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    // Function to load in SMS messages no longer being called on API 28
                    getAllSms(getContext());
                }

     return view;
}


@WithPermissions(permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS})
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void getAllSms(Context context)
    {
        HashSet<String> phoneSet = new HashSet<>();
        phoneSet.add(SelectedPhNo);  // phoneNumber
        long threadId = Telephony.Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(context, phoneSet);
        Uri threadUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Telephony.Threads.CONTENT_URI, threadId);

        String[] projection = new String[] {Telephony.MmsSms.TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN, BaseColumns._ID, Telephony.Sms.Conversations.THREAD_ID,
                Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, Telephony.Sms.BODY, "sort_index", Telephony.Sms.DATE_SENT, Telephony.Sms.DATE,
                Telephony.Sms.READ, Telephony.Sms.TYPE, Telephony.Sms.STATUS, Telephony.Sms.LOCKED,
                Telephony.Sms.ERROR_CODE, Telephony.Sms.SEEN, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.BODY, Telephony.Sms.Sent.BODY};

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(threadUri, projection, null, null, "normalized_date desc");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur);

        // Read cursor into an arraylist
        ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        int totalSms = cur.getCount();

        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < totalSms; i++)
            {
                String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.BODY));
                String indexDate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.DATE));

                // Convert string to long variable
                Long date = Long.parseLong(indexDate);

                // Convert millis value to proper format
                Date dateVal = new Date(date);

                //"dd-MMM-yyyy""dd/MM/yyyy"
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss  dd-MM-yyyy");
                dateText = format.format(dateVal);

                cur.moveToNext();

                inboxArrayAdapter.add("Command: " + body + "\n" + "Date: " + dateText);

                Log.e("Body", body);
                Log.e("Date", dateText);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at SMS retriever API. It restrict you getting access to SMS unless your app satisfy certain criterias. I think this may be the issue.

Comment: The code for retrieving the SMS was working fine before. Is it something to do with the compilier or API version. All required permissions for reading sms have been enabled.

Comment: Yup it has deal  with API version.

Comment: What I don't understand is that is exact code was working completely fine the other day, it's just when I recomplied it, the method was no longer being called.

Comment: New restrictions are imposed to stop apps accessing all SMS unless it is selected as default SMS app or fall in the criterias decided.

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html?m=1

Comment: So I'll need to write extra code to get around this to be able to read sms messages from the inbox

Comment: Unless you fall in the criterias mentioned or you can read just otp msgs sent with predefined format.

Comment: Could it be also to do with min Sdk Version because I currently have it set at 22 but those runtime permissions are in API 23